# Grails: How to make a g:textfield autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, autocomplete, textfield

I have a g:textfield, and I want to write something and then show me all the options possible that start  with the same letter. I understand that is called AutoComplete.

Maybe using jQuery or JavaScript??
Any ideas??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can see answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433858/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-grails/10470005#10470005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using an existing plugin:

- [jQuery plugin: Autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)
- [Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/)

If have problem to use it with `<g:textfield>`, [Here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/jQuery-Autocomplete-td2526439.html) is a thread that may help you to implement.

Answer (score 0):

say you are going to autocomplete on a 'thing' field

1. you need an autocomplete widget, jquery has one, that you use for the thing field
2. you need a server endpoint that finds 'things' based on what the user types in.  this endpoint will return json.

thats really it.  as you mentioned, the widget will use ajax to query the server when the user types in the field, and it will use the response to draw a div that contains possible completions.

Comment: @fgualda87  which part do you need help with?