# jquery-ui autocomplete in grails

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, grails, grails-plugin

Can anyone give me the complete steps to work with jquery-ui autocomplete. I am using grails 2.0.1.

I need a complete example including code for controller and views.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first you need to add in your main.gsp (in head) this to lines

```
 <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
 <g:javascript library="jquery-ui"/>
```

the plugin will downloaded automatically.

and for complete example you can use this link

http://jay-chandran.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-grails-with-jquery-autocomplete.html

Answer (score 7):

you should really try to do this yourself and then ask a question about how something works or why something is not working.

but a good place to start is the general jquery - ui documentation

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

and then you could run through a simple example like this:

http://ohmiserableme.blogspot.com/2011/08/grails-jquery-ajax-autocomplete-with.html